# Does Julia have a "yield" like paradigm?

Tags: julia

Reading back through some of my old Python code to refresh myself on the "Yield" keyword, I realized that I have not seen a similar idea in Julia. Does an analog version of Yield exist? (Note that Julia's Base library comes with a `yield` function but that is for tasks and does not act like the yield keyword does in Python).

Comment: `yield` in python is used for generators. Something similar in julia happens automatically under the hood afaik. For example, you can't use `1:10` as a range of numbers directly but you can use `collect(1:10)`. Similarly, a numerical range returned as a generator by a python function would have to be converted to a list first.

Comment: I think the closest approximation to `yield` is to define a function that returns a value given some state (say, the index), then return a generator that calls that function over a range of states. e.g., `function f(i) ... end; (f(i) for i in 1:10)`

Comment: Python's generator functions (`yield` instead of `return`) are basically shortcuts for iterators (1-2 classes with `__iter__` and `__next__` methods). Julia implements iterators with 2 `Base.iterate` methods. I can imagine structuring `Base.iterate` like a Python generator function, but it'll be a bit awkward. Like everywhere there would be a `yield`, you return a integer marking your place, and the method is itself a giant if statement that checks the integer to know where to pick up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no built-ins for `yield` (unfortunately, if you ask me).  However, since Julia has a very advanced macro system, and the theory as well as multiple possible implementations of coroutines/generators are quite well studied, there are a couple of implementations in third-party packages.

One of them is [FGenerators.jl](https://github.com/JuliaFolds/FGenerators.jl), previously GeneratorsX.jl, which works mostly in the transducers ecosystem.

Another is [ResumableFunctions.jl](https://github.com/BenLauwens/ResumableFunctions.jl).

Answer (score 1):

You can construct generators that yield values when iterated upon:

```
f(x) = x*x
g = (f(i) for i=1:5) #generator that yields values

for x in g
    println(x)
end
```